# Error: Failed to execute postMessage in Window [Angular2]

Tags: javascript, angular

I've created a Google authentication module for Angular 2. One of my user having this problem while using Google App Engine. -

#### Code -

```js
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  imageURL: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
  token: string;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private zone: NgZone) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    AppGlobals.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = Constants.client_id;
    this.getData();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.googleAuthenticate();
      gapi.client.load(Constants.nameProyect, 'v1', null, '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
    }, 2000);
  }

  googleAuthenticate() {
    this.auth.authenticateUser((result) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.getData();
      });
    });
  }

  getData() {
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.imageURL = localStorage.getItem('image');
    this.name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    this.email = localStorage.getItem('email');
  }

  logout() {
    const _this = this;
    this.auth.userLogout(function () {
      _this.clearLocalStorage();
    });
  }

  clearLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('image');
    localStorage.removeItem('name');
    localStorage.removeItem('email');
  }
}
```

#### Error -

[image]

GitHub issue URL - https://github.com/rudrakshpathak/angular2-google-login/issues/1